# Localhost keeps refreshing

Tags: wamp, xampp

I was using xampp 2 weeks ago perfectly. But, now, whenever i am trying to connect localhost, it does not appear and keeps refreshing. I know what happens when the port is used by other programs which appears as "not found" or so. But, now, i have no errors or no results. Only refreshing the page... What is the problem? I reinstalled many times even changed the service but the result is the same

Comment: `"keeps refreshing"`. Does it end in a "Too many redirects" message?

Comment: When i enter localhost in the browser, the page seems it is going to that page but it does not return any results. i waited about 10 minutes but nothing happens

Comment: Perhaps you're serving up a page with a meta refresh tag? What does the apache log(s) say? Use browser dev tools, curl, telnet etc to inspect the content of the page being served up. Is it empty?

Comment: That is weird. Could it for some reason be unable to resolve localhost? Try `127.0.0.1` as well. After that, I'd suggest checking if the apache service is actually listening on port-80.

Comment: Also when i was trying to uninstall the xampp, i could not delete mysqld.exe file. Is this the error?